# Is "Fünfzigerjahremusik" a Determinativkompositum?

Tags: noun, spelling, compound

I am unsure about the correct spelling of "Fünfzigerjahremusik" - does this word fall under the category of Determinativkompositum?

Or would you rather spell it as "Fünfzigerjahre-Musik"? If yes, which rules would apply?

Comment: @Saha / Stefah Bitte nicht in den Kommentaren antworten.

Answer (score 1):

> Man **kann** einen Bindestrich setzen zur Hervorhebung einzelner
> Bestandteile, *zur Gliederung unübersichtlicher Zusammensetzungen*, zur
> Vermeidung von Missverständnissen oder beim Zusammentreffen von drei
> gleichen Buchstaben.
> ([§ 45 Amtliches Regelwerk des Rats für
> deutsche Rechtschreibung](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6159#par45))

One could argue here that it is a "unübersichtliche Zusammensetzung" and accordingly write "Fünfzigerjahre-Musik" with a hyphen.

However, since it is a "may" provision, this view does not have to be shared.
POV: Both variants are decent, but i really like the readabilty hyphens provide, others may feel otherwise.

As @Saha stated, that is different, when using "50er-Jahre". The according rule could be also found in the "Regelwerk" (§ 42).

---

I don't really understand why it matters if it's a determiner compound, maybe you can elaborate on that. (*Apfelbaum*, *Glatzkopf* und *Fahrradfahrer* are "also" written without hyphen).